# Android lint enable checks with gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, lint

I want to execute some of the 11 disabled checks. The [Android Lint documentation](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint) just said about this

> Some checks are disabled by default. These can be enabled by adding
>   the **--enable** flag.

How can I activate them for my gradle build? I can't find any options to do that within the `build.gradle` or `lint.xml` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Lint Support](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Lint-support)

> As of version 0.7.0, you can run lint for a specific variant, or for
>   all variants, in which case it produces a report which describes which
>   specific variants a given issue applies to.
>
> You can configure lint by adding a lintOptions section like following.
>   You typically only specify a few of these; this section shows all the
>   available options.
>
> ```
> android {
>     lintOptions {
>         ...
>         enable 'RtlHardcoded','RtlCompat', 'RtlEnabled'
>         ...
>     }
> ```

Comment: Can you enable StopShip check this way? I'm having a hard time trying to make it work :s