# How to make Grade release build fail using Lint Option StopShip?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-lint

I've read a lot about the `StopShip` Android Lint Check and Gradle support for it

- http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks
- http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Lint-support
- http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions:checkReleaseBuilds
- [Android lint enable checks with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108809/android-lint-enable-checks-with-gradle)
- [gradle build fails on lint task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699147/gradle-build-fails-on-lint-task)
- http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html
- http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html

I would like to use as some here in SO have already mentioned, instead of a TODO or FIXME comment, use it to ensure a code block intended for development/debugging/testing does not reach production.

For this, I would like to do 2 things:
- enable StopShip check, as it is disable by default
- change severity from warning (default) to error

(assuming that we use `abortOnError true` on our gradle config).

I am failing to achieve this! No matter what I tried android build does not fails if I add a `// STOPSHIP` comment in my code. Which is odd, since in the textEditor its highlighted as an error and if I run a Lint check (Analyze > Inspect Code...) it is listed as one of the issues.

Here's what I've tried in my `build.gradle`

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds true
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError true
    enable 'StopShip'
    error 'StopShip'
}
```

I have also tried to change my Android Studio preferences in File > Settings > Project Settings > Inspections (or Android Studio > Preferences > Inspections on Mac). Here I checked the `Code contains STOPSHIP marker` and changed the severity to error but still nothing.

Here's what my `lint.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="BackButton" severity="warning" />
    <issue id="EasterEgg" severity="warning" />
    <issue id="FieldGetter" severity="warning" />
    <issue id="IconExpectedSize" severity="warning" />
    <issue id="RtlCompat" severity="error" />
    <issue id="RtlEnabled" severity="warning" />
    <issue id="RtlHardcoded" severity="warning" />
    <issue id="SelectableText" severity="warning" />
    <issue id="StopShip" severity="error" />
    <issue id="TypographyQuotes" severity="warning" />
    <issue id="UnusedIds" severity="warning" />
</lint>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally cracked it! `fatal 'StopShip'`. That's what finally did it! Leaving my discovery in case it helps anyone.

Replacing `error 'StopShip'` with `fatal 'StopShip'` in my `build.gradle` config solved the problem.

I don't fully understand why my previous attempts with `error 'StopShip'` didn't work, as the [abortOnError docs](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions:abortOnError) clearly state:

> Whether lint should set the exit code of the process if errors are found

and I was marking the `StopShip` check severity as error. It looks like `abortOnError` will only make the Gradle build abort for FATAL errors. Can anyone confirm?

Of course, if it anyone offers a better solution/explanation, please do share.

Comment: The default for `StopShip` is `warning`, and `error` and `fatal` work the same way for me combined with `abortOnError`, as expected. (Using Gradle plugin 1.5.0)